# Python nested import

Tags: python, import, file-structure

I can't get my mind around this problem

Let's suppose we have a file structure

```
Folder
├── main_file.py
├── Subfolder
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── file_a.py # def foo()
│   ├── file_b.py # from file_a import foo; def bar(...use function foo())
```

How can I use function *bar* in my *main_file.py* without nothing going wrong, because if I only import function *bar* from *file_b* it throws me error: **'there's no module named file_a'**

Thank you for answer

**edit** thanks, I only have trouble with some imports inside my file, so after adding the *Subfolder.* to all imports it works well
**Thank you**

Comment: In this setup it would be `from Subfolder.file_b import bar`

Comment: Put the code you use to do the import to help you better in solving your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the **RELATIVE** directory w.r.t main_file.py. In this case you can find and import the function bar like this :

```
from Subfolder.file_b import bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the directory you're importing from.
Specify the file path like this:

```py
from Subfolder.file_b import bar
```